# 90's sci-fi show in which a sergeant-type character called his men "space butts" or "star butts"

Tags: story-identification, tv

I think it was a 90's show.  I've done all the searching I can think of.

I want to say it was *Babylon 5* or *Space: Above & Beyond*, but I just don't know.

I remember thinking it was kind of funny to add 'space' or 'star' next to butt, instead of calling them a-holes or whatever.  Lazy sci-fi writing at its best: add 'space' and you know it's future times!

A detail I remember: a bunch of soldiers fighting in a bar, different branches of service, something like that - then showing two of the guys who were really going at it in the brawl at the end of the show, lying among the dead very close to one another after a battle. The implication was they were blowing off steam while not on duty, but brothers to the end in combat. It was quite touching.

One more detail: it was a US production.

Comment: Thanks for adding more details! I've cleared up the comments, but please do keep helping the OP to narrow down more details to add. While I have you OP, please do look at the [help] and [tour] for an introduction to the site.

Comment: Thank you for helping me along with my grammar and syntax, @AncientSwordRage.  I'm usually better, but lazy writing has been my thing for awhile.  Nice to be involved with a site that cares about those things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The character you're  thinking of is [Sergeant Major Plug](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Plug) from ***[Babylon 5](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105946/?ref_=tt_ov_inf)*** (1993–1998).

He appears in S02E10, "[GROPOS](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/GROPOS):"

> General Richard Franklin, father of Stephen Franklin, arrives on Babylon 5 with an army of 25,000 Earthforce Marines ("Ground Pounders" or GROPOs as they are also known) about to be deployed in a war zone.

At around 13 minutes into the episode, there's a scene where Plug addresses some of the Earthforce marines under his command as "star-butts:"

> COMMANDER IVANOVA: Dr. Franklin.
>
> DR. FRANKLIN: Yes.
>
> COMMANDER IVANOVA: We're short of space. I'm afraid we're gonna have to billet these people in the infirmary.
>
> DR. FRANKLIN: Absolutely not. This is a medical facility, not a damn barracks.
>
> COMMANDER IVANOVA: Sergeant, would you please take your people through there? I'll be with you in a minute.
>
> SERGEANT MAJOR PLUG: Yes, ma'am. **You heard the commander, star-butts.** Get it in gear! Move it, you mutant maggots!

At around 18 minutes into the episode, there's a scene where [Private First Class Elizabeth "Dodger" Durman](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Elizabeth_Durman), gets into a fist fight with [Private Kleist](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Kleist) and two other marines, who were behaving threateningly towards [Delenn](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Delenn), due to their racial prejudice against her species, the [Minbari](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Minbari). Plug breaks up the fight and chews the four marines out.

> [image: Image of Sergeant Major Plug from Babylon 5.]

At around 36 minutes into the episode, Private Kleist starts another fight with [Lieutenant Warren Keffer](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Warren_Keffer) over a spilled beer, kicking off a mass brawl between the Earthforce marines and pilots. Plug breaks up the fight again, but is accompanied by [General Richard Franklin](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Richard_Franklin) this time, who promptly orders the troops into battle. Private Durman was caught up in this fight as well, along with [Private First Class "Large" Turnbow](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Turnbow), played by Ken Foree of *Dawn of the Dead* (1978).

In the closing shots of the episode, we see

> Privates Durman, Kleist and Turnbow

all lying dead in the aftermath of the battle.

Comment: I am reminded of the Albert Brooks comedy Lost in America he is ironically congratulated for coming up with a sound effect in a scifi flick. The guy says to Brooks, You saved the movie! and they discuss that this is the sound of someone running on "Space Floor".